# MongoDB - _id remains null after insert operation version 3.2.8 on debian 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, debian

When I run `db.collection.insert({
    "_id": null,
    "test": "Test config text......"
    })`

The `_id` attribute remains null after insert, it should be generated. This only happens on debian. Have no problem with this on Mac running the same code.

is there any settings for this?

Comment: What do think you mean by "remains null"? If you explicitly supply a value then that is what is "always" used. There is no circumstance where that `null` is going to be swapped for another value when issuing `.insert()`. You are getting confused with something else it seems. The general idea is to "not supply any value for `_id` at all. In that case it is "always generated". But **never** when you actually supply a value.

Comment: yes I got confused because my mac always swapping the the value of _id whatever it is. But that is probebly some bug in that mongo version.. Now it works fine. Thanks